# $\cal P(\omega)/fin$, automorphism, number of, $\aleph_1$,CH

Tags: ideals, cardinals, boolean-algebra, forcing, automorphism-group

Under CH, $\cal P(\omega)/fin$ is atomless Boolean Algebra saturated and has cardinality $\aleph_1$. Why?

It has $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ automorphisms. Why exactly?

Comment: Why is it unclear that it has cardinality $\aleph_1$?

Comment: Some justification would help. It is very likely, but not obvious to me.

Comment: CH states that $\mathcal P(\omega)$ has size $\aleph_1$. And clearly $\mathcal P(\omega)/\textrm{fin}$ is uncountable. Is this enough justification? :)

Comment: OK....and the rest is that easy as well?